# Simple AppleScript to send SMS by Messages app fails with error MacOs Monterey 12.0.1

Tags: macos, applescript, sms, message

I wish to automate the sending of SMS texts using AppleScript to control the Messages app in MacOS Monterey (12.0.1). My very simple test script fails with an error message as below:

```
tell application "Messages"
    send "Test" to participant "123456789" of account "SMS"
end tell
```

Running the script fails with this error:

*error "Messages got an error: Invalid key form." number -10002 from account "SMS"*

Obviously, I am using a valid phone number (my own) which is among my contacts (in fact, Script Editor recognizes the number and offers additional info via a drop down list).
The MacBook Pro M1 I'm using is setup to send and receive text messages, I use that all the time. I get the same result if I try to send an iMessage by replacing "SMS" with "iMessage". Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
tell application "Messages"
    launch
    repeat while (count of windows) is 0
    end repeat
    set a to first account whose service type = SMS and enabled is true
    set p to participant "123456789" of a
    send "test, please ACK" to p
    -- properties of p
end tell
```

Note: You may not be able to text yourself, and you may need to already have texted the recipient.

Answer (score -1):

```
tell application "Messages"
    set iMessageService to 1st account whose service type = iMessage
    set imessagebuddy to participant "00301234567890" of iMessageService
    send "ignore the last messages. just testing. i am still the applescriptmaster" to imessagebuddy
end tell
```